# Mutliprocessing for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, dataframe, tensorflow

I've got 101000 images. My goal is to translate them into vectors using tensorflows resnet50. Doing that works just fine but it would take 20+ hours to translate all of them with my current code.
Now I'm looking for a way to process them in parallel, but haven't had much success with it.

Here's my code:

```
   def return_image_embedding(model,img_path):
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        preds = model.predict(x)
        curr_df = pd.DataFrame(preds[0]).T
        return curr_df  
     model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
     img_path = 'food-101/images/10500.jpg'
     return_image_embedding(model,img_path)  
     images_path = os.listdir('food-101/images/')
     embedding_df = pd.DataFrame()  
     for curr_img in tqdm(images_path):
        curr_df = return_image_embedding(model,'food-101/images/' + str(curr_img))
        curr_df['image'] = curr_img
        embedding_df = pd.concat([embedding_df, curr_df],ignore_index=True)  
     embedding_df.to_csv(r'./embeddings.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=True)
```

And I tried this which definitely did not work:

```
  def loop(curr_img):
        curr_df = return_image_embedding(model,'food-101/images/' + str(curr_img))
        curr_df['image'] = curr_img
        embedding_df = pd.concat([embedding_df, curr_df],ignore_index=True)
        return embedding_df  
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    new_df = pool.map(loop, images_path)
```

Any help is appreciated!

By the way, I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: What is the value `mp.cpu_count`? Also, you are using embedding_df in loop, it is also creating race condition. In pool.map, you should get the list which you need to convert to the format you want.

Comment: Simply, return curr_df from loop. Refer https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool for pool.map

Comment: As suggested by documentation, use imap.

Comment: It will good if you can measure the time taken by steps and find the time consuming step. Refer: https://pynative.com/python-get-execution-time-of-program/

Comment: Sorry to say but you are doing it all wrong, you are predicting one image at a time, load a batch of images and use the largest batch size that your hardware will support. Samples inside a batch are parallelized in most implementations.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy sounds better then what i'm doing. Do you got any refferences, where i can look up how to do that? Or examples? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really, its just using the batch size parameter of model.predict, and providing more than one sample to predict.